# Problema com executável python gerado pelo pyinstaller

Tags: python, cmd, .exe, pyinstaller

Fiz um software simples em python com interface gráfica. Fiz o build com o pyinstaller e ao tentar abrir o executável gerado, o prompt de comando do windows também é aberto todas as vezes. Já me indicaram alterar a extensão do arquivo que contem o main de **".py"** para ".pyw", mas não resolveu. Alguém saberia como ajudar?

Answer (score 3):

Eu tive um problema muito parecido e consegui resolver com o comando:

```
pyinstaller --noconsole exec_main.py
```

Verifique se ajuda.

Referência: [Windows and Mac OS X specific options](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#windows-and-mac-os-x-specific-options)

Comment: Valeu, cara! Obrigado! Funcionou legal :D

Comment: Perfeito @Daniel Souza. Se for possível poderia marcar  a resposta como válida? Abraço.

Comment: Pode ser que ao gerar esse .exe o programa ao converter não considera os imports não nativos se utiliza libs baixadas tem que indicar os packages dessas libs.